# How to make flexbox responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I have a div with two elements that I want to stack horizontally. Div#C has fixed width, and div#B will fill up the rest of the space. However the contents of div#B might be fixed width (which is dynamic) or 100% width (of div#B).

The effect I want is, if the screen width is small enough such that, right before div#B and div#C start to overlap or if the width of div#B is small enough, I want div#B and div#C to stack vertically, and each have width 100% of div#A. The problem is if I use a media query, I have to give a fixed min width for it to stack horizontally. With a fixed width, it doesn't account for any fixed width content in div#B. Does anyone know how to fix this preferably only in CSS?

```css
#A {
    display:flex;
}
#B {
    flex:1;
}
#C {
    width:300px
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
    <div id="B">b</div>
    <div id="C">c</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This, I think, is not possible. CSS can't detect when the flex-container will wrap...nor can any other layout method for that matter AFAIK.

Comment: Then again, perhaps it can...

Answer (score 7):

Although I had initially thought this might not be possible there is one option I can think of.

Give `div#B` a ridiculous `flex-grow` value in comparison and give `div#C` just `flex:1 0 300px`

```css
div {
  padding: 2em;
}
#A {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#B {
  flex: 99;
  background: pink;
}
#C {
  flex: 1 0 300px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
  <div id="B">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div id="C">c</div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/grErAX)

When `div#B` eventually shrinks small enough to force wrapping, the `flex-grow:1` on `div#C` wil cause it to expand to full width and the 'upper' `div#B` will now take up the full width also since it cannot expand past 100% width of that 'row'

[image]

Comment: Why do you refer to `flex-grow` yet code just `flex`? I don't know much about flex but interested

Comment: The full version of the `flex` *shorthand* property has 3 values for is `flex-grow flex-shrink flex-basis` so it should be written `flex: 99 0 auto` but the last two are the default values so they can be missed off and we can write `flex:99` instead.

Comment: I put a table in div#B, and then when I tested div#C started to overlap on div#B table.

Comment: There's no mention of a table in your question. Tables can have different behaviours in flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a simple way

```css
.container{
        display:flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }

      .container div {
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 1em  1em;
        flex: 1;
       }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
      <h4>
       First box
      </h4>
      <p>
        dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make 
         dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make  dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make  dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make  dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make 
      </p>
  </div>
  <div>
     <h4>
       Second box
      </h4>
      <p>
        dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make 
      </p>
  </div>
  <div>
     <h4>
       Third box
      </h4>
      <p>
        dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make 
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#A {
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
#B {
    flex-basis: 60%;
}
#C {
    flex-basis: 40%;
}


@media (max-width: 540px){
   #B {
        flex-basis: 100%;
        //whatever width you want in mobile view
    }

    #c {
        flex-basis: 100%;
        //whatever width you want in mobile view
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use media queries to get this done. Set the break point like 767px or 992px to stack the divs vertically.