# How do i make a flexbox responsive

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hi I'm trying to make my `nav_list` class is not responsive i have used the following code, but when I test on browser it isn't responsive gets cut from view.

```css
/*queries*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .nav_list {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 2%;
  }
}


/*css*/

.top_nav {
  display: flex;
}

.nav_list {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 150px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav_list">
      <li class="nav_list_item"><a>Sign in</a></li>
      <li class="nav_list_item"><a>What is Shi</a></li>
      <li class="nav_list_item"><a>Sign up</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make flexbox responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38976978/how-to-make-flexbox-responsive)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making flexbox responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49956169/making-flexbox-responsive)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is media query and flex-direction: column.
For example, if overflow occur in 768px, then you would need to change your flex direction from row (default) to column view.

```
.nav_list {
            display: flex;
        }

    @media (max-width: 767.98px) {
        .nav_list {
            flex-direction: column;
        }
    }
```

Or a smarter way flex-wrap:

```
.nav_list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```